# Getting Text from Repeater in Protractor

Tags: jasmine, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in menulist" ng-class="isActive(menu.type, menu.complete)" ng-click="setTopNav(menu.type, menu.complete)">{{menu.label}}</li>
```

Is the code for our menu. I'm trying to detect an array of the label names with

```
this.menuNav = element.all(by.repeater('menu in menulist').column('label'));
```

I bring that page object in a test and try to use the assertion

```
expect(navHeader.menuNav[1].getText()).toEqual('Label 2');
```

And I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getText' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protractor returns a promise, you need to change your code into

```
element.all(by.repeater('menu in menulist').column('label')).then(function(elems) {
    expect(elems[1].getText()).toEqual('Label 2');
});
```